# Java Array Sort and Filtering

Tags: java, sorting, filtering

So I have a "csv" file that contains info like:

```
PersonName,Likes,Dislikes,DOB,MOB
John Lauzon,Games,,14,09
Jane Smith,Music,,15,02
Hugh Mungus,Jokes,,01,04
```

---

This code sorts that array by DOB (date) and it should filter it by the value in txtBDays, which represents MOB (month of birth) and displays the result in a Text Area called "txtDisplayArea" but the filter bit doesn't work properly

```
public void getBDays() {        
    for (int i =0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
        sortArray[i] = FriendInfo[i].getDOB() + "\t" + FriendInfo[i].getMOB() + "\t" + FriendInfo[i].getName() + "\t" + FriendInfo[i].getLikes() + "\t\t" + FriendInfo[i].getDislikes();
    }
    Arrays.sort(sortArray, 0, numberOfEntries);       

    txtDisplayArea.setText("Birthdays for the month of: " + txtBDays.getText() + "\n\n");
    txtDisplayArea.append("Date \tMonth \tName \t\tLikes \t\tDislikes \n");
    txtDisplayArea.append("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
        //if (txtBDays.equals(FriendInfo[i].getMOB())) {
        if (txtBDays.getText().equals(FriendInfo[i].getMOB())) {
            txtDisplayArea.append(sortArray[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

---

By default the value in txtBDays in the current month so it's 03 for March but when I run the application the filtering doesn't work properly. Here's a link of the screenshot of the results.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6S30gKlNFC5c2xhNkhQbktjZzg

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `sortArray`, and did you define a `compareTo` method?

Comment: The filtering (obviously) does not work as `txtBDays.getText()` returns a value which is _not equals_ to `FriendInfo[i].getMOB()`, so the first thing to to is add a `System.out.println(String.format("[%s] == [%s]",txtBDays.getText(), FriendInfo[i].getMOB()))` to your _for_ loop, and check if the values you are trying to compare are really equvivalent.

Comment: @zeppelin It's giving this.
[03] == [03]
[03] == [03]
[03] == [03]
I took a look at the csv file and saw 3 result and I tried it with other number and it seems to work. I'm just having trouble displaying the results.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm a beginner so I'm bound to make mistakes but as far as I know is a String array and apart from the line, if (txtBDays.getText().equals(FriendInfo[i].getMOB())) { there's no compareTo method.

Comment: `[03] == [03] [03] == [03] [03] == [03]` so getMOB() basically always returns `03`, which matches your filter, so all the lines are included in the results, if you data does not match that (i.e. there are other values for MOB), you should look inside the 'getMOB()', to see if it really returns a correct field.

Comment: Also note that you are comparing the filter text with the FriendInfo array entries (which is an unsorted array), and then use the same index, to output a line from the _sorted_ array, which won't produce the results you need (even if the filtering issue is resolved), as FriendInfo[] indexes do not match sortArray[] indexes.